# Firebase Storage taking up unusually high bandwidth and requests

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have been using react-native-firebase's storage API in my react-native project and I have encountered this problem in which 5 (or sometimes more) requests are being made to firebase storage on my app boot up.

However there is just one call to the `getDownloadUrl` function made in the code. This leads to unusually high network bandwidth consumption.

The following is the code which calls `getDownloadUrl` -

```
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import storage from "@react-native-firebase/storage";

const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
//Setting dp from storage
  const dp = await storage().ref(`/profiles/${uid}/0`).getDownloadURL();
  dispatch({ type: SET_DP, payload: dp });
```

And this code runs exactly once in the `useEffect` of the home screen.

The following are my firebase storage security rules -

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
            allow write: if request.auth != null;    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if any more information is required, thanks a lot :)